# Clear Datetimepicker field. Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, dynamics-crm-portals

When a section is hidden in my Dynamics Portal I want to clear the DateTimePicker field in that section.

I have tried this and many similar functionalities:

$('#myDateField').datetimepicker("clearDates");

I get this error:
Uncaught Error: bootstrap-datetimepicker("clearDates") method was called on an element that is not using DateTimePicker.

'myDateField' is the ID of the field when I do an inspect on the date field.

I am unsure if I am using the method wrongly or simply point to the wrong field ID

Comment: May you provide a snipet with html and javascript to illustrate your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I was calling the datetimepicker in a wrong fashion. Due to the way the datetimepicker is wired up, it should be accessed and cleared like this:

```
$('input[aria-describedby="myDateField_description"]').val(null);
```